# Redirection in windows shortcuts

Tags: windows, shortcut, netsh, lnk

I have a batch file that looks like this:

```
netsh interface dump > net.cfg
```

And I would like to run the actual command from a shortcut, so I tried all of this (in the `.lnk` shortcut):

```
%windir%\system32\netsh.exe interface dump > net.cfg
%windir%\system32\netsh.exe interface dump>net.cfg
%windir%\system32\netsh.exe "interface dump" > net.cfg
%windir%\system32\netsh.exe "interface dump > net.cfg"
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start /min netsh interface dump > net.cfg
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start /min netsh interface dump>net.cfg
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start /min netsh "interface dump" > net.cfg
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start /min netsh "interface dump > net.cfg"
```

And nothing seems to be working... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close with the quotes...

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "netsh interface dump > net.cfg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k netsh interface dump > net.cfg
```

Source: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/257/cmd-create-shortcut-to-command-linedos-programs/